# Redirect all pages from old domain to a specific page website

Tags: html, .htaccess

I want to rebrand my website. Example:

old.com

new.com

both websites are hosted on the same hosting (redirects to same public_html folder.)

For primary website I can't change the path public_html folder.
I don't want old.com to redirect to new.com, I want to redirect all pages from old.com to old.com/rebranding.html

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

if the server is Apache based you can use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) if it's installed/enabled

```
RedirectMatch ^/* https://new.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^rebranding\.html$ http://old.com/rebranding.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

`!^rebranding\.html$` will redirect only when current URI is not `/rebranding.html`

Comment: Yes sure just comment out above `RewriteCond` line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect all pages on old.com to new.com/rebranding.html and you have access to the .htaccess file then you can use a custom 404 page and remove all files in old.com, place this in the .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /redirect.html
```

And then place the following html in redirect.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://new.com/rebranding.html'" />
    </head>
</html>
```

For more information regarding the .htaccess file you can go here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html